# PHP MySQL: issue selecting different columns from the same table

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

This has surely come up before but I haven't found a solution. I am trying to select username and password from a database to verify users a simple login script. It should simply find a row in the users table with a username and password matching those submitted through the login form.

I can match the username without any problem but not the password and I have no idea why.

The table contains columns called "username" and "password" and there is only 1 row in the table with a username 'admin' and a password 'testpassword'.

Here is the function containing three options - options 1 and 4 work, the other two don't. Option 2 is the same as option 1 except it looks up a different column. I have checked that the column name in the query matches the columns in the table and that the submitted values match. I'm not getting any error messages and can't see what might be wrong (something basic, I'm sure...).

```
function new_session ($username, $pw, $inactive) {

    // echo statements verify that variable match database values
    echo "<h2>username = " . $username . "</h2>";
    echo "<h2>password = " . $pw . "</h2>";
    echo "<h2>inactive = " . $inactive . "</h2>";

    $db = mydb::getConnection();

    //option 1
    $statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :parameter');
    $statement->bindValue(':parameter', $username);

    //option 2
    //$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = :parameter');
    //$statement->bindValue(':parameter', $pw);

    //option 3
    //$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = :parameter1 AND username = :parameter2');
    //$statement->bindValue(':parameter1', $username);
    //$statement->bindValue(':parameter2', $pw);

    //option 4
    //$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "admin" AND password = "testpassword"');

    $statement->execute();
    $row = $statement->fetchAll();

    if (count($row) == 1) {
        // SESSION data is set here for options 1 and 4
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is the password stored in an encrypted form?

Comment: when trying to troubleshoot queries. i try to write the query in plain text form and run it.  If i can't get results like that then i need to edit my base query before trying to edit in code form

Comment: option 3 has the params in the wrong order. param 1 should be pw and param 2 should be username. That should work fine

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to check is if the passwords in your data base are hashed. They probably should be, and if they are you need to compare using the hashing function `PASSWORD`

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = PASSWORD(:parameter)');
$statement->bindValue(':parameter', $pw);
```

Now, if your passwords aren't hashed (shame on you), you might have a different problem. As you can see in the above, `password` is a function name in mysql. It might be having problems parsing your statement because you are using `password` as a column name. Put `tick-marks` around the column name `password`. Like this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE `password` = :parameter');
$statement->bindValue(':parameter', $pw);
```

Notice that those are `tick marks`, not a single quote. They are found on the same key that <kbd>~</kbd> is on, above the tab key. These `tick marks` will indicate that `password` is a column name.

Answer (score 2):

The word "PASSWORD" is a mysql command. so escape it first like this:

```
 //option 3
    //$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE `password` = :parameter1 AND username = :parameter2')
```

If this query gives error, then I think you have your password encoded.
Then use this for md5:

```
$statement->bindValue(':parameter', md5($pw));
```

And for sha1:

```
$statement->bindValue(':parameter', sha1($pw));
```

I see no other errors which might could result in no rows :o

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions and taking time to look at this, I have escaped the word password as suggested however I'm ashamed to say the problem was that the maxlength on my password form input was trimming the last character and I didn't spot it.

Comment: Don't worry mate. At least you will know about this now. And you can prevent to happen it next time. This is how we all learn!